# Training Dataset of N-dimension in Logistic Regression using scikit-model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have training dataset of 200 images with dimension 28 x 28.I stored it in train_dataset with shape 200 x (28 *28).Labels are one dimension of shape 200.
i.e. **Training: (200, 28, 28) (200,)**
I need to fit this training data in scikit-model of logistic regression.i.e. **fit(train_dataset,train_label).**
But fit parameters of  fit(X, y, sample_weight=None) have array(X).dim < 2 and
also array(Y).dim < 2.
So is there any alternative to **scale down train_dataset** but it would take a great amount of space i.e. 2d array of size 200 x (28 * 28) and also map the same to train_label of 1-d dimension ?
How to train such train_dataset having **dimension>=3**?
Is it possible to generalize same to n-dimension.
Error while training :

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if dealing with images its always a nice idea to apply `PCA` or Principal Component Analysis to reduce the dimension of your data set.

`.fit()` accepts a 2D array so **you have** to ravel it down so that the function accepts it but you can apply PCA to get like 60 features capturing most of your variance for example and get a dataset of shape (28*60).

More about PCA [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).